# Using latest panda APIs to compute exponential moving average

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, moving-average

I have a python v3.6 function using panda to compute exponential moving average of a list containing floating numbers. Here is the function and it is tested to work;

```
def get_moving_average(values, period):
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    values = np.array(values)
    moving_average = pd.ewma(values, span=period)[-1]
    return moving_average
```

However, `pd.ewma` is a deprecated function and although it still works, I would like to use the latest API to use panda the correct way.

Here is the documentation for the latest exponential moving average API.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#exponentially-weighted-moving-window-functions

I modified the original function into this to use the latest API;

```
def get_moving_average(values, period, type="exponential"):
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    values = np.array(values)
    moving_average = 0
    moving_average = pd.ewm.mean(values, span=period)[-1]
    return moving_average
```

Unfortunately, I got the error `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'EWM'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ewm()` method now has a similar API to `moving()` and `expanding()`:  you call `ewm()` and then follow it with a compatible method like `mean()`.  For example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randn(5)})

df['x'].ewm(halflife=2).mean()

0   -0.442148
1   -0.318170
2    0.099168
3   -0.062827
4   -0.371739
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

If you try `df['x'].ewm()` without arguments it will tell you:

> Must pass one of com, span, halflife, or alpha

See below for documentation that may be more clear than the link in the OP:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html#pandas.DataFrame.ewm

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows